# Jquery Mobile Paste event on input text

Tags: jquery-mobile, onpaste

I'm using Jquery Mobile to develop an web app for Android and iPhone. I want to handle the event when the users change their value in the input text field.

Initially, I use `.on("keyup change")` and everything seem to work ok. However, when the users paste some text on the text field (by holding and tap on the "Paste"), my event handler is not called.

Please help me if you know how to solve this problem.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

**Works on all browsers but not on FireFox.**

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/spMcF/)**

```
$('input').on('paste', function (e) {
 if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
  var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
  $('p').empty();
  $('p').append(text);
 }
});
```

> Credit goes to: [jQuery Detect Paste Event Anywhere on Page and "Redirect" it to Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131617/jquery-detect-paste-event-anywhere-on-page-and-redirect-it-to-textarea)

Comment: I tried the "paste" event, but it not worked on iPhone and Android.

Comment: I tested it on iOS 7 and it is working, but still no luck with android.

Comment: @BharatPatil this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167381/android-paste-event

Comment: @Omar - I am using Phonegap.

Comment: @BharatPatil then for sure you can find a command in Phonegap/Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

1. For Android add a timeout as it is in this example http://ajax911.com/numbers-numeric-field-jquery/
2. For iPad add event 'change' together with paste, worked on iphone

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me on mobile Safari and Chrome.

```
if (document.getElementById('search_input')) {
    document.querySelector('#search_input').addEventListener('paste', (e) => {

        let pasteData = (e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text');
        pasteData = pasteData.replace(/[^\x20-\xFF]/gi, '');
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            //do stuff
        });
    });
}
```