# Get paste event for WYSIHTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, wysihtml5

I have an WYSIHTML5 editor and I wrote a paste handler to paste images in site, as attachments. The problem is that I want the pastehandler to work when I hit paste inside the WYSIHTML5 editor also.

I've registered to paste event like this

```
 this.editor.observe("paste", this.pasteHandler);
```

but the problem is that my pasteHandler needs the event that fired it as a parameter, but the observe function it's not sending the event.

How can I send this event from WYSIHTML5 editor to my paste handler?

Comment: would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16221918/1771795

Comment: sorry but it's not working. I tried to bind the event on the editor's text box, but the event it's not dispatched. Using the all above, the pasteHandler gets called, but has no parameter (event) so I can't access clipboardData.

Comment: can you show your html code?

Comment: I don't believe it's necessary. I only have an ordinary WYSIHTML5  editor that I have to put it listen to a paste event. As I said, i don't know how I can pass the original event as a parameter to my pate handler.